# Automatic Power On and Off

Tags: automation, power-on, power-options

Is it possible to configure a smartphone with Android 8.1.0 to power on and off at specified times?

Comment: not exactly what you want, but you can schedule airplane mode with automation apps like MacroDroid. disable SIM PIN protection if you want to receive calls. for kids control there are several other solutions

Answer (score 1):

Some OEM ROMs offer such a functionality, most do not. You can check your device's settings, if there is such an entry. If there is none, then it is not possible. So, the answer to this question will be a yes and no together. It will depend on which smartphone you have.

You can certainly not achieve this with 3rd party apps.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked the smartphone's settings and have not found the option to schedule powering on the device. Are there custom-made Android ROMs which have greater functionality?